# Fix pixels in menu

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, menu, pixel-perfect

I am designing a menu using bootstrap3. It should look like the one shown in the picture. But I am unable to create a menu like that. I have tried creating one and the link to my design is https://codepen.io/irshad437/pen/EyQLVv.
Some code is also shown below. **But you must check it on Codepen.io** (NOT LOOKING GOOD HERE)

```
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">MyGrade <span class="circle-txt">Up</span></a>
    </div>

    <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li><a href="#">HOME</a></li>
        <hr class="vertical" />
        <li><a href="#">EXPLORE</a></li>
      </ul>
      <form class="navbar-form navbar-right" role="search">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default btn-rnd">Create Portfolio</button>
      </form>
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><a href="#">Anonymous <br />0 pts</a></li>
      </ul>
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <img class="img-circle nav-img" src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/677716/profile/profile-80_1.jpg" alt="?" class="img-round"/>
      </ul>
    </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
  </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
</nav>
```

```
.btn-rnd{
  border-radius:10px;
}

.navbar-nav li{
  margin-left:20px;
  margin-right:20px;
}

.nav-img{
  width:40px;
  height:40px;
}

.vertical{
  position:absolute;
  width:1px;
  height:25px;
  color: black;
  background-color:black;
  display:inline-block;
}

.padding-8{
  padding-top:8px;
}

.img-circle{
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.circle-txt{
  height: 40px;
  width: 40px;
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: -10px;
  padding-top:8px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: white;
  border-style:solid;
  border-width:1px;
}
```

**Problem:** I am unable to fix the pixels at the proper position as shown in the design.

[image: this is how it should look.]

Comment: look into css flex

Comment: use vertical-align:middle.

Comment: @CarolMcKay what do you mean?

Comment: @Leothelion I have tried vertical-align. but it didn't work

Comment: Well for it did for mygrade and up..but for other you have to check code as you have wrong values for some tags.

Comment: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/ http://flexbox.io/#/

Comment: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/LkdPjw
use this. Just change some. It's properly aligned.

Comment: @HayleyKiara no its not even what op asked. Op wants with bootstrap so please don't change the aim of question.. Thanx

Comment: @Leothelion Okay. Just giving him option. I'm just trying to help him as far as I can. I apologize to all of you. I promise, I won't do this again.

Comment: Its great that you want to help but point is op is doing work with bootstrap and if he will try with new technology then it will be time consuming and might be delay in his work. We all here to help so don't make yourself down. Cheers :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work fine, Have a look, here is the fix.

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/QEmZWR

HTML:

```html
<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">MyGrade <span class="circle-txt">Up</span></a>
    </div>

    <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li><a href="#">HOME</a></li>
        <hr class="vertical" />
        <li><a href="#">EXPLORE</a></li>
      </ul>
      <form class="navbar-form navbar-right" role="search">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default btn-rnd">Create Portfolio</button>
      </form>
      <ul class="annon nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><a href="#">Anonymous <br />0 pts</a></li>
      </ul>
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <img class="img-circle nav-img" src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/677716/profile/profile-80_1.jpg" alt="?" class="img-round"/>
      </ul>
    </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
  </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
</nav>
```

CSS:

```css
.btn-rnd{
  border-radius:10px;
}

.navbar-nav li{
  margin-left:20px;
  margin-right:20px;
}

.nav-img{
  width:40px;
  height:40px;
}

.vertical{
  position:absolute;
  width:1px;
  height:25px;
  color: black;
  background-color:black;
  display:inline-block;
}

.padding-8{
  padding-top:8px;
}

.img-circle{
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.circle-txt{
  height: 40px;
  width: 40px;
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  padding-top:8px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: white;
  border-style:solid;
  border-width:1px;
}

a{
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}

.navbar-nav li{
  margin-top:10px;
}

.navbar-form .btn{
  margin-top:10px;
}

.annon li{
  margin:0px;
} 
.navbar-nav .img-circle{
  padding:0xp;
  margin-top:13px;
}
```